# Repeated nodes in tree-decomposition of a graph is allowed or not?

Tags: graph-theory

As we know, a [*tree-decomposition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_decomposition) of a graph must have following features:

1. All vertices are covered
2. All edges are covered
3. The connectivity condition

I think using repeated nodes in *tree-decomposition* must be allowed by definition. Is it true?

**Edit:**

The answer is [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/225880/repeated-nodes-in-tree-decomposition-of-a-graph-is-allowed-or-not).

Comment: What do you mean of repeated node?

Comment: @Hoseyn Heydari, Assume you have created some nodes in a tree-decomposition so that all edges and vertices covered. Repeated nodes are nodes that copied from existent nodes and added to the tree-decomposition with retaining of connectivity condition.

Comment: As it stands, your question is quit imprecise. Consider adding a full definition of _tree decomposition_ (including references where appropriate).

Comment: @Arthur Fischer, tree-decomposition is a known structure. Do you think it's necessary to define it again? In this case we must also define "graphs" when we ask a question about them (for example)! Whether or not, I'll set the Wikipedia reference in my question :)

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact, you must also define "graphs" when you ask a question about them. Can a graph have multiple edges? Can it have loops? Are the edges directed? Can the vertex set be infinite? Can the vertex set be empty?